# How can I router FooterLink to InfoSection in React.Js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have  a footer menu, when I click the footer items, it should be rooter to page info section.

**Products.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { InfoSection } from '../../components';
import { homeObjOne, homeObjTwo } from './Data';

function Products() {
return (
<>
  <InfoSection {...homeObjOne} />
  <InfoSection {...homeObjTwo} />
</>
);}
 export default Products;
```

**Footer.Js:**

```
       <FooterLinkItems>
        <FooterLinkTitle>Products</FooterLinkTitle>
        <FooterLink to='/'>Products</FooterLink>
        <FooterLink to='/'>Info</FooterLink>

      </FooterLinkItems>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I get it. Once the user clicks on the link in the footer it will take him to another page but into a specific section/component?

You would need to create a `ref` to the section.

Something like:

```
...

export const sectionRef = React.createRef(); // used to anchor to

...

return (
    <section ref={sectionRef}>
       ...
    </section>
```

then:

```
import { sectionRef } from '../..';

<FooterLink linkRef={sectionRef} text="Info" />
```

and:

```
export const FooterLink = ({ linkRef, text }) => {

   const handleClick = () => {
    linkRef.current.scrollIntoView({
      block: 'start',
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
   };
 
return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      {text}
    </button>
```

is it what you need?

This link might help https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/innerref-refobject

Comment: tnx so much u understand question, but. ur answer not solve it